# How to save a file using nano

Tags: nano

I am trying to install Java via the terminal using the guide *[How to Install Oracle Java JRE on Ubuntu Linux](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JRE-on-Ubuntu-Linux)*.

Everything went perfectly fine until "*Step 11: Save the /etc/profile file and exit*":

[image]

I spent maybe 30 minutes figuring out what `^` means (apparently <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), but I cannot understand how that guy called the save command where you can choose `yes` and `no`.

I did try `^O`, but I didn't get the same result as he did. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but anyway, you have an error in the script in your screenshot. `JAVAJAVA_HOME` should be just `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 174):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> will quit the editor and you will be asked if you want to save your changes. If you do, press <kbd>Y</kbd> for `Yes`.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> should also work, since that means to save the file, but you won't be asked "*Save modifier buffer ?* " because you already told `nano` to save.

Comment: i am editing etc/bluetooth/main.conf file. When I do ctrl+X , it shows filename to write and its in var/tmp/mainxxejQnI3.conf? Is this correct behavior?

Answer (score 50):

One can save changes via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> which actually means Write Out while editing a file through [`nano`](http://www.nano-editor.org/docs.php):

[image: nano]

Where `^` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

*Note* : You'll also have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to overwrite the existing file if it exists.

Comment: correct...and one has to press `Enter` to save it after pressing `Ctrl+o`,then press `Ctrl+x` to exit

Answer (score 8):

With the image [shown right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCKRv.jpg) you can save just pressing "Y" for yes. To know what key combinations you need to do just check the White square besides the action, which are as follow:

- Y: yes
- N: no
- Ctrl + C: Cancel

Answer (score 3):

I am using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to quit.