# How do I save and quit after making changes in a config file?

Tags: nano

How do I save and quit after making changes in a config file? I was told to type out the command `:wq` but I do not know where.

I'm met with this screen. Which keys do I press to type out the `:wq` command?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a file using nano](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477603/how-to-save-a-file-using-nano)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `:wq` is for a different editor than the one you are using.

The one that you are using, asks you to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to output (write) the file, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit

Comment: also, ctrl+x with unsaved changes will trigger a "do you want to save?" prompt

Comment: +1, even though OP is basically trying to drive screws with a hammer and you're saying he's "really close" ;)

Comment: @gronostaj I understand - My point is that the OP is trying, which is more than a lot of the other questions I've seen :)